# How can I enable swipe for back in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, gestures

Recently bought a new tablet, its running Android 6.0. On my touchscreen Windows 10 laptop, I can swipe the screen with one finger to go back and forward in chrome.

How can I do the same the same on Chrome for Android?

I've searched the internet, but can only find custom apps to perform this function. I have never installed anything custom to get this working on Chrome for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

With newer version of Chrome for Android, it's possible to go back or forward by swiping left or right from the edge of the screen. If it's not enabled by default, follow the steps below:

1. In the address bar, type `chrome://flags`.
2. In the flags search box, type "history navigation".
3. You will either find depending on your Chrome version "Enable gesture navigation" or "Overscroll history navigation". Click on Default, then select Enable.
4. Restart Chrome.

Swiping left or right from the edge of the screen on tabs will take you back to the previous page or forward to the next page.